# How to Use RibbonControl in C#.Net?

Tags: c#

My image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m9P5.png)

I am starting with RibbonControl in Devexpress. My problem is

1. Change Font Size in sub-item, if the font size is bigger than 10, it ran out of the area.
2. I need it to read my character in Unicode font.

There is any way to make the font area auto size with the font size?

Comment: You need to post some code you've tried or no one will be able to help!

Comment: Have written no any code in this design form. I have just design it from the properties. I am not sure that it is possible to resize the font or not.

Comment: You might be better off posting this on the devexpress forum. It's only a matter of time before people start getting angry and down voting your question for lack of code. Sorry I can't help!